# Could you please check my machine integer?

Tags: c, abstract

i got a little problem with my integer machine, si it's an abstract integer machine, from the textbook i need to make a RESET and INC (increment) button. The RESET button set the final state with 0, and INC button increment the value of current integer, so when we push the INC button 5 times, the output will be 5, here's what i got, could you guys please check ? Thanks

```
void RESET (int CI){
    CI = 0;
}

void INC (int CI, int Value){
    CI = Value;
    CI = Value + 1;
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass the variable by value, therefore its value won't be updated outside the function. You need to pass the variable by reference:

```
void RESET (int *CI){
    *CI = 0;
}

void INC (int *CI, int Value){
    *CI = Value + 1;
}
```

and call the function like so:

```
INC(&your_variable, 5);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I  really appreciate it, but the output is 6 if I put 5 in it, so put

    printf("%d\n", Value -1);